# Facebook iOS SDK: How to Persist Login to File or Database?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm fairly new to iOS development, and I'm starting work on an App that will include some simple Facebook integration. As a proof of concept, I made a bare-bones, view-based application that has a simple button to log a user in to Facebook, and then another button to post a status update.

This is all well and good, but in a real world scenario, a user shouldn't have to login to Facebook every time they want to use the Facebook-integrated features of my App. My question is this: how would I go about persisting a user's login to a file, or to a database for use in a later launch of my App?

Ideally this solution would use Facebook's iOS SDK, but I wouldn't be opposed to building my own authentication system using their Graph API. The advantage of using Facebook's official iOS SDK, though, is that it can use the login information already associated with the phone's Facebook application (if installed), or the login associated with facebook.com on mobile Safari.

I'm not providing my current source code, on the basis that this is a general enough question to not require the specifics of my Facebook SDK usage. However, if you think it would be helpful, I'd be more than happy to post my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wouldn't do that. check out facebook SSO in their SDK ( see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ ). You request the facebook token everytime you use it or otherwise get an long-term (read: use access token offline_access) access token and persist this token to the NSUserDefaults for use in your app. ( see http://coffeeshopped.com/2011/01/saving-sessions-with-the-facebook-ios-sdk )

Comment: So the best solution is to request offline_access when authenticating? I know about SSO, but that doesn't really address my issue, which is having to authenticate for every use.

I'll try requesting offline_access and saving the token to NSUserDefaults. Thanks!